# javascript custom sort when parts of an array has no data

Tags: javascript

I have an object model that looks like this:

```
MyObject = {
   TheName: "",
   OtherProps :....
}
```

I have an array of these objects and my custom sort function looks like this:

```
function SortArray() {

  var CustomFunction;

  var CustomSortAsc = function (a, b) {
    return a['TheName'] - b['TheName'];
  }

  var CustomSortDsc = function (a, b) {
    return b['TheName'] - a['TheName'];
  }

  if (SomeCondition) {
      CustomFunction = CustomSortAsc;
  } else {
      CustomFunction = CustomSortDsc;
  }

  SomeArray.sort(CustomFunction);
}
```

`SomeArray` has somewhere around 200-300 objects in it and the problem is that sometimes the object has an empty `TheName` property. Because of that, the sort doesn't seem to work as expected. For instance, if there are values then sort by name and then put all the values for which there are no names according to the sort function.

What's the way to make this work? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Would something like `return (a['TheName'] || 0) - (b['TheName'] || 0);` work (since you're using `-`, I'm assuming the values are numbers)?

Comment: You are sorting with `a - b` which will result in `NaN` for most strings. If both are empty strings, you will get a legit value of `0`

Comment: @Rocket: no, they're strings.

Comment: @frenchie: If they are strings, then you cannot use `-` to compare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your TheNames are strings, you probably better use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead:

```
var CustomSortAsc = function(a, b) {
    return (a['TheName'] || '').localeCompare(b['TheName'] || '');
};
```

And I'll probably write it all like this:

```
var baseSort = function(a, b) { 
  return (a['TheName'] || '').localeCompare(b['TheName'] || '');
};
var CustomFunction = SomeCondition 
                   ? baseSort 
                   : function(a, b) { return -baseSort(a, b); };
```

UPDATE: and if you need to see the empty values the last all the time...

```
var CustomSortAsc = function(a, b) {
    return a['TheName'] === '' 
         ? b['TheName'] === ''
           ? 0
           : 1
         : b['TheName'] === ''
           ? -1
           : a['TheName'].localeCompare(b['TheName']); 
};
```

... or, if you prefer `if`:

```
if (a['TheName'] === '') {
  if (b['TheName'] === '') {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
} else {
  if (b['TheName'] === '') {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return a['TheName'].localeCompare(b['TheName']);
  }
}
```

*(is this actually more readable?)*

Comment: I'm getting an error Object MrJones has no method localCompare.

Comment: @frenchie: There's an *e*: [local_e_Compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: @raina77ow: unfortunetly, it's a whole single page app working on my machine; can't provide a live example.

Comment: ok, the local compare works when I'm sorting descending (names first sorted z through a and then the blanks) but the problem is that when I'm sort ascending I'm first seeing all the blanks before the names are sorted a through z.

Comment: ok, the thing is that the values are never null; they're just empty strings. I think the ? conditional syntax makes the code hard to read, especially when there are nested conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A custom sort function **must** return a number (<,= or > 0). If it returns anything else (like `NaN`), the behaviour is "implementation specific" (according to the standard), which means it usually breaks and just sorts nothing.

I'm not sure what you are trying to sort for ('TheName' sounds like strings, your function is for numbers), but you should just return 1 if the property does not exist on b and -1 if on a; then your property-less items will be sorted to the end of the array.